# Excel VBA Sharing Variable Within Userfrom Subs

Tags: excel, vba, variables, global, userform

So this isn't a huge deal, but it's getting under my skin. I'm trying to share a variable between subs *within* a userform. Declaring a public variable seems like an easy way to do it, but apparently, you can't declare public variables from within a userform. So it seems I have to declare the variable in a completely unrelated module, which I find maddeningly annoying. Is this the only way to pass variables between subs within a userform?

For context, I'm trying to make "Ok", "Apply", and "Cancel" buttons on a Settings userform, where the "Ok" and "Apply" buttons permanently make changes that I made in the settings.

Here's button that's removing items from a listbox (PathList). The listbox is storing data on a worksheet, but I don't want the items to actually be removed from the sheet until I hit "Apply". I want to share the SelectedArray() variable with the ApplyButton_Click subroutine so that the "Apply" button can actually delete the cells from the sheet. The commented code is what I want the "Apply" button to do.

```
Private Sub RemovePathButton_Click()
Dim SelectedArray()
Dim ctr As Integer
ctr = 1

For intCount = PathList.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If PathList.Selected(intCount) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve SelectedArray(ctr)
        SelectedArray(ctr) = intCount
        ctr = ctr + 1
    End If
Next intCount


For i = 1 To UBound(SelectedArray)
'    Dim num As Integer
'    num = SelectedArray(i) + 4
'    Worksheets("Settings").Range("A" + CStr(num)).Delete (xlShiftUp)
    PathList.RemoveItem (SelectedArray(i))
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a variable on the top of UserForm Module, the variable can be accessed by any control or a procedure on the UserForm Module.

Insert a UserForm and place two command buttons on it and place the following code on UserForm Module.
Launch the UserForm and click both the command buttons to see how can you access a variable this way.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Str As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox Str
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call Test
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Str = "This variable can be accessed by any code on UserForm Module."
End Sub

Sub Test()
MsgBox Str
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be simple like that. Does this work with regular modules as well? Simply declaring the variable before all the subs shares that variable within the module?

Comment: @AlecHolmes You're welcome. Yes that's true. That's called module level variables if you declare them at the top of module.